# Calculate area in hA creating multiples fields using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3

I'm writing code that add some attributes. I need create an attribute, 'AREA_HA', and to calculate the area in HA. My code works well, but doesn't create the attribute 'AREA_HA' and calculation produces no result. I looked at some answers here in stack, but none applied to the structure of my code. How I can improve it?

```
path = 'D:/shps/SHP'
for root, directory, files in os.walk(path):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith('.shp'):
            full_path = os.path.join(root,file)
            vlayer = QgsVectorLayer(full_path,file[:-4],'ogr')
            feats = vlayer.getFeatures()
            for feat in feats:
                geom = feat.geometry()
                if geom.type() == QgsWkbTypes.PolygonGeometry:
                    vlayer.startEditing()
                    vlayer.addAttribute(QgsField('ID',QVariant.String, 'string',50))
                    vlayer.addAttribute(QgsField('STUDY',QVariant.String,'string',100))
                    vlayer.addAttribute(QgsField('PROJECT',QVariant.String,'string',100))
                    vlayer.addAttribute(QgsField('STAGE',QVariant.String,'string',100))
                    vlayer.addAttribute(QgsField('DATE',QVariant.String,'string',30))
                    vlayer.addAttribute(QgsField('COMPANY',QVariant.String,'string',50))
                    expression = '($area/10000)'
                    field = QgsField('AREA_HA', QVariant.Double, 'double',19)
                    vlayer.addExpressionField(expression, field)
                    vlayer.commitChanges()
                print(vlayer)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a number of issues here. Firstly, with the `addExpressionField()` method, you are trying to add a virtual field to a `QgsVectorLayer` object which is not loaded into a project, which simply won't work. Virtual fields are added to the end of an attribute table in a project vector layer and exist only in the project settings in which they have been created. They cannot be permanently added to the layer's data provider. Please see the first point under the Note section [here](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/attribute_table.html#creating-a-virtual-field).

Other than that you have some logic errors e.g. you are adding fields to the layer for every feature, so you should move that section out of the feature iterator loop. Also you need to call `updateFields()` after adding the fields.

I strongly recommend studying the [PyQGIS Developer Cookbook](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/index.html), especially the following sections:

[Modifying Vector Layers](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/vector.html#modifying-vector-layers)

[Expressions with features](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/expressions.html#expressions-with-features)

Try the following script:

```py
path = 'D:\\shps\\SHP'

for root, directory, files in os.walk(path):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith('.shp'):
            full_path = os.path.join(root,file)
            vlayer = QgsVectorLayer(full_path,file[:-4],'ogr')
            if not vlayer.isValid() or not vlayer.geometryType() == QgsWkbTypes.PolygonGeometry:
                if not vlayer.isValid():
                    print(f'Layer from {file} not valid')
                if vlayer.geometryType() != QgsWkbTypes.PolygonGeometry:
                    print(f'Layer from {file} not a polygon layer')
                continue
            vlayer.dataProvider().addAttributes([
                QgsField('ID', QVariant.String, len=50),
                QgsField('STUDY', QVariant.String, len=100),
                QgsField('PROJECT', QVariant.String, len=100),
                QgsField('STAGE', QVariant.String, len=100),
                QgsField('DATE', QVariant.String, len=30),
                QgsField('COMPANY', QVariant.String, len=50),
                QgsField('AREA_HA', QVariant.Double, len=19, prec=9)
            ])
            vlayer.updateFields()# Need this line!
            
            e = QgsExpression('$area/10000')
            c = QgsExpressionContext()
            c.appendScopes(QgsExpressionContextUtils.globalProjectLayerScopes(vlayer))

            att_map = {}

            for ft in vlayer.getFeatures():
                c.setFeature(ft)
                att_map[ft.id()] = {vlayer.fields().lookupField('AREA_HA'): e.evaluate(c)}
                
            vlayer.dataProvider().changeAttributeValues(att_map)
```

Comment: Hi @ben-w, The code worked! Thanks a lot!!! I had a problem with a path, but now i'ts ok. Now, i have to calculate the x anf y coordinates using the same logic from Polyline but to Points.